# wpa_cli: interactive shell works, single commands fail?

Tags: wpa-supplicant, wpa-cli

I'm trying to connect to wifi using the wpa_cli. I've run `$ wpa_cli add_network`, got 0 back, ran `$ wpa_cli set_network 0 ssid "my ssid"`. But this failed. Then I tried the interactive shell, ran `set_network 0 ssid "my ssid"` and got an OK? Shouldn't both either fail or run just fine? Why is only one failing?

Comment: Maybe it is a quoting issue try to quote your quotes when you are running it from the shell: `... ssid '"my ssid"'`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, but do you know the reason why it is like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell does something called *word splitting* (which you can read up on in detail).  For most situations (and yours here) this means that on the command line if you want to pass any of a small set of special characters to a program you have to protect them.  To protect them you have to either prefix them with a backslash (`\`)  or surround the text in question with quotes.

<sub>Sidenote: Single quotes are in a sense "stronger" as no characters have special meaning inside.  Double quotes allow for some characters to retain their special meaning inside.</sub>

As you might have guessed from the name "word splitting" white space is one of the things that you need to protect when you want to pass it to a program. But from the quoting rules above it should be obvious that also quotes and backslashes need to be protected.

The problem is that wpa_cli expects (double?)quotes around the SSID but yours wear "eaten" by the shell because they where not protected.  Now with `wpa_cli set_network 0 ssid '"my ssid"'` the single quotes protect the double qoutes and the wpa_cli command sees `"my ssid"` as its fourth argument.